# jQuery: on Clicking any Menu Link, Play Animation and Only Then Go to the Link's URL

Tags: jquery, url, jquery-animate

When any of the menu links is clicked, I want to play a quick animation on the current page, and only then go to the url of the clicked link.

I would be grateful for the expertly help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prevent the default behaviour, play your animation and then point the browser to the original destination.

```
$('#menu a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = this.href;

    $('#whatever').animate({
        top: '300px'
    }, 500,
    function() {
        window.location = href;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Alex, this is perfect, just want I wanted! Thank you for the jsfiddle example Jesus! You guys are the best! Extremely helpful!

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to you both, this example helped me a lot!

I was wondering on how to expand on this, let's say I want that #whatever to move 300px to the top and AFTER that -  opacity: 0;

So basically I want to know how to make an animation sequence before executing the href.

I tried using timeouts, but it doesn't work. With this I can only ''fire'' all at once.

---

Edit:

Ok, I figured it out on my own. I'm not sure why it works (mainly because of my limited javascript knowledge) but it does, here's the script:

```
$('#menu a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = this.href;

    $('#whatever').animate({
        height: '500px'
      }, 700);
    $('#whatever').animate({
        width: '500px'
      }, 1000);
    $('#whatever').animate({
        opacity: '0'
      }, 1200,
    function() {
        window.location = href;
    });
});
```

Looks like the timeout isn't necessarry, these animations are displayed in a sequence.

If I understand correctly, that script works like this:

1. it get's defined that the link won't have it's default value
2. something happens with it
3. at the last part of something happening, the link receives back it's
   default value

---

Edit2:
Ok, let's get this a bit more complicated. Let's say I want to animate two elements but not at the same time. Now this looks like a situation for a timeout, then again becuase each of those functions are happening in a sequence, I can fake a timeout by animathing nothing. For example, I added #block which is 200px wide and at first I'm animating it's width to... 200px, so nothing happens which is exactly what I want. But there should be a proper way how to do it, can anyone shed some light on this? Why are those animations happening in a sequence and what is the proper way how to set timeouts (delay animations)?

```
$('#menu a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = this.href;

    $('#whatever').animate({
        height: '500px'
      }, 700);
    $('#block').animate({
        width: '200px'
      }, 1000);
    $('#block').animate({
        width: '500px'
      }, 1200);
    $('#whatever').animate({
        width: '500px'
      }, 1000);
    $('#whatever').animate({
        opacity: '0'
      }, 1200,
    function() {
        window.location = href;
    });
});
```